# How to find the size of the sparse files in the filesystem ext2?

Tags: c, filesystems

Is there a way find the size of the sparse files in the filesystem ext2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the `stat()` of the file. The field `st_size` gives the regular size in bytes, including holes. The field `st_blocks` shows the actually allocated blocks (in units of 512 byte blocks), so `st_blocks * 512` is the number of bytes it actually takes up on disk.

This works on any filesystem, not just ext2.

Comment: Is each block is 512 bytes length. I saw somewhere that it is 4096 for a 32bit system

Comment: @Angus That field is given in 512 byte blocks always. The field `st_blksize` gives you the preferred block size for file I/O, which is very possibly the block size of the filesystem. But `st_blocks` is given in 512 byte blocks always.